# itunes connect set price for new app version

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

I've a new version of an App that's ' waiting for review' and when it is released to the app store I want this new version to be free whereas the current version is paid. There doesn't seem to be a way to set a separate price for the version in review. Have any other folks ran into this and solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I suggest is to ensure the the new version is not released automatically - use the 'Pending Developer Release' system - and then set the price to free and release the new version simultaneously.

You may be able to automate this part by setting the date of the price change to the date of the release of the new version - but I haven't tried this myself so I don't know if they'd happen simultaneously.

If you were doing the opposite - converting your app from free to paid - there's no Apple-friendly way I know of to prevent users of the free version getting the paid-for updates.

Comment: Interesting idea... There seems no way to access the 'Pending Developer release' system once the app is in 'waiting for review' state though. Do I have to reject the app from review and start over?!

Comment: I had to 'developer reject' my app and set the release date my self in order to change the price to free once the new version is approved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

are you talking about allowing people who have already bought it to update for free ?

If so this is how its works, the update replaces the old app on the app store, those that have paid for it get the update for free while those who want to buy it for the first time have to pay, when they pay they get the latest version.

Comment: No, the new version will be free to new downloaders. I've converted the app from a paid-for app to a free one with in-app purchase.

Comment: Can't help you with your question, but remember to detect if the user already had the previous version of the app installed, or they would have to pay for the new version. I would be pissed if upgrading an app, caused me to have to pay again, with no possibilty to downgrade back to the old version.

Comment: Yes, am detecting existing previous versions.